# Maximum expected absolute value for a random variable with zero mean and unit variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Over the set of all random variables $X$ s.t. $\mathbb E [X] = 0$ and $\mathrm{Var} [X] = 1$, what is $\sup \mathbb E [|X|]$? Which $X$, if any, achieve(s) this maximum?

In other words, what is the distribution with zero mean and unit std dev which has the highest expected absolute value?

Comment: Are you asking which _distribution_ maximizes the expected absolute value?

Comment: @JohnBarber yes. I edited the question a bit, but feel free to edit further if you think it helps to clarify.

Comment: It would improve your Question to sketch what motivates you to ask, or what difficulty was found in researching this problem.  Context is very helpful to Readers composing a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking about this problem, for me the first and simplest candidate for such a distribution would be:

$$\rho (x) = 0.5 * [\delta (x-1) + \delta (x+1)] $$

It is clear that the expectation value of the absolute value of $x$ equals $1$.

You can now try to improve om this result by adjusting the above formula. E.g. by adding a delta function in the origin, or by adding two delta functions symmetrically, i.e. in $c$ and $-c$.

Comment: @John: Are you sure? This here seems to contradict what you say: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution. Also, the Cauchy Schwarz inequality should show that one cannot get more than 1.

Comment: You're right. I made a dumb arithmetic error. The Gaussian actually gives roughly 0.8.

Comment: I think your first guess with the $2$ delta functions is the correct answer.

Comment: @PhoemueX I would appreciate (and upvote) an elaboration of the statement "the Cauchy Schwarz inequality should show that one cannot get more than 1".

M.Wind: thanks! Out of the 3 distributions I looked at, this "coin flip" distribution is the best. The Gaussian has a value of sqrt(2 / pi) or about 0.80, and the uniform has a value of sqrt(3 / 4) or about 0.87. So this provides a bit of empirical evidence that the coin flip distribution is the best.

Comment: They're right about the C-S inequality. Let $f(x)$ be the pdf of x. Then the average absolute value is $\left<|x|\right> = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx |x| f(x)$. Divide the integrand into $|x|\sqrt{f(x)} \times \sqrt{f(x)}$, apply C-S, and you get $\left<|x|\right> \leq 1$.

Comment: @Kerrick: Cauchy-Schwarz shows that $E[ |X| ] = E [1 \cdot |X|] \leq \sqrt{E[1^2]} \cdot \sqrt{E[|X|^2]} = 1$, where I used that $\mathrm{Var}(X) = E[X^2] = E[|X|^2]$, since $E[X]=0$. Feel free to post this as an additional answer yourself if you want.